# android obb file location in internal memory for 4.0 - 4.4

Tags: android, android-resources, apk-expansion-files

Help please solve my problem with obb files, I add downloader_library to my project, when application start he download for me obb file, this worked good. 
If file stored in external sd card no problem,app work, but when I try on telephone without sd card my app is crash. I look to method which look if obb file exists and I see he always look on sd card, How I can find my obb file in internal memory ?

This method looks if obb file exists:

```
 static public boolean doesFileExist(Context c, String fileName, long fileSize,
        boolean deleteFileOnMismatch) {
    // the file may have been delivered by Market --- let's make sure
    // it's the size we expect
    File fileForNewFile = new File(Helpers.generateSaveFileName(c, fileName));
    if (fileForNewFile.exists()) {
        if (fileForNewFile.length() == fileSize) {
            return true;
        }
        if (deleteFileOnMismatch) {
            // delete the file --- we won't be able to resume
            // because we cannot confirm the integrity of the file
            fileForNewFile.delete();
        }
    }
 return false;
}
```

This method - Helpers.generateSaveFileName use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

fileForNewFile for 4.0 - 
/mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.example.app/main.1.com.example.app.obb
fileForNewFile for 4.4 - 
/storage/sdcard/Android/obb/com.example.app/main.1.com.example.app.obb

How I understand and read in internal memory obb must be somewhere in /data/data/com.example.app but how receive this directory ? And what real path:
/data/data/com.example.app/obb/main.1.com.example.app.obb ? 
/data/data/com.example.app/Android/obb/main.1.com.example.app.obb ?

On phone (4.4.2) without sd card file manager show me path after download - /Android/obb/com.example.app/main.1.com.example.app.obb but phone without root and i don't see upper directory where is this Android folder.

I completely confused please help.

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are trying to read (the one with *data/data*) is the `getFilesDir()` result. Can you try here: `/mnt/obb/packagename/` with the regular *read storage* permission? The *obb* folder should already exist (at least for emulators).. Other paths should already be constructed if you tried to access folders using the tutorial given on the Android developers website.

Also you don't need root to access the files through ADB, and you can push/pull them through ADB as well with basic commands